# ADO text file query - results split by comma

Tags: vba, excel, ado

I am querying a text file using ADO to bring the data into Excel.

```
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & filePath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties='text';"

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM " & fileName, cn

wsImport.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

The issue I'm facing is that the query results are being split, by comma as a delimiter. This means that when I write the data to the worksheet, it's being output across several columns.

I've confirmed that it's being split at the query stage, and not at the writing of the data to the worksheet stage. I have to use `rs.Fields(0)` and `rs.Fields(1)` to access some rows of data, when I want all of the data to be accessible within the first field of the created recordset (allowing the data to be written to column A of the worksheet).

Can anyone clarify how I can query the text file, whilst not splitting the data by any delimiter?

I've also tried using the below within the Extended Properties.

```
Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited';
```

and

```
Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=FixedLength';
```

Comment: You'd need to create a schema.ini file but I can't really see why you'd use ADO at all here rather than just reading the text file into a variable, splitting into an array at each new line character and then just drop the array into the sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Rory. Happy to consider your suggestion if you could provide an example of how this would work? I've always worked with text files in this way, on the assumption that it was the quickest method of getting data from a text file and into Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example of reading the text file:

```
Sub foo(filePath As String)
    Dim sDataIn                     As String
    Dim sDataTemp()                 As String
    Dim sDataOut()                  As String
    Dim n                           As Long

    Open filePath For Binary As #1
    sDataIn = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , sDataIn
    Close #1
    sDataTemp() = Split(sDataIn, vbNewLine)
    ReDim sDataOut(1 To UBound(sDataTemp) + 1, 1 To 1)
    For n = LBound(sDataTemp) To UBound(sDataTemp)
        sDataOut(n + 1, 1) = sDataTemp(n)
    Next n
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(sDataOut), 1) = sDataOut
End Sub
```

Comment: That's awesome - this seems like a much cleaner way of working with text files. Thanks! How come you set the `sDataIn` variable to spaces (same length of text file), instead of just assigning the text file data to the variable straight away?

Comment: In binary mode, the number of bytes read is equal to the number of characters already in the variable.

Comment: Makes sense - thanks for explaining, very much appreciated. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on the macro recorder and let it record you doing all the steps one time to import a file, you should have your answer.

I just tried it and got this.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\your_path_here\test.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "test"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```